# Mock / stub with integration testing in Java

Tags: java, mocking, integration-testing, stubbing, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured for integration testing on my endpoints.  One of the endpoints has a dependency to another resource (it calls another API conditionally).  Is there a way for me to stub out the API call so I can write a test for that case?

Comment: If you separate the retrieval of data from the manipulating of it and outsource it to an interface with implementation, you can use contructor or setter injection to inject your own testdata.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel can you provide an example?

Comment: I have posted an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your code calls endpointB internally via http, you can stub that api by using https://github.com/katta/fakerest or https://stubby4j.com .So when your code makes a call internally to the another api, it will hit these stubs, which will return a dummy response always. Hope this helps.

Comment: They both require running another process while running the JUnit tests right?

Comment: Yes, you have to start them before you run your rest assure test cases. As rest assure does not have mock or stub(as far as i know), we have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IDataProvider {
 string RetrieveData();
}

class StandardDataProvider : IDataProvider {
 public string RetrieveData(){
  // call to API
 }
}

class Program {
 private IDataProvider _dataProvider;

 public Program(IDataProvider provider = null) {
  _dataProvider = provider ?? new StandardProvider();
 }

 public void MethodToTest(){
  var data = _dataProvider.RetrieveData();
  // do your thing
 }
}
```

In the tests you can mock the data by creating your own `IDataProvider` object and working with its data.

```
class TestDataProvider : IDataProvider {
 public string RetrieveData(){
  return "my own data";
 }
}

class Test {
 [TestMethod]
 public void TestProgram(){
  var obj = new Program(new TestDataProvider);
  var result = obj.MethodToTest();
  // asserts
 }
}
```